# How to add Body request in url in Kotlin?

Tags: json, kotlin, android-volley

Here is my Code that for Volley Request:-

```
val searchRequest = object : JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,
        Response.Listener { response ->

            val result = response.toString()


        },
        Response.ErrorListener { error ->
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Error!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show()
            Log.d("ERROR",error.toString())
        })
{
    override fun getBody(): ByteArray {

       //   TODO add Body, Header section works  //////////

        return super.getBody()
    }

    override fun getBodyContentType(): String {
        return "application/json"
    }


    override fun getHeaders() : Map<String,String> {
        val params: MutableMap<String, String> = HashMap()
        params["Search-String"] = songName
        params["Authorization"] = "Bearer ${accessTx.text}"
        return params
    }
}
AppController.instance!!.addToRequestQueue(searchRequest)
```

I want to add this information in the body section

video_id = "BDJIAH" , audio_quality = "256"

here is the sample to add above information in the below segment.

{ "video_id":"ABCDE", "audio_quality":"256" }

Basically, I am facing problem in ByteArray section. That doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **toByteArray()** method of String class in Kotlin.

For example:

```
val charset = Charsets.UTF_8
val byteArray = "SomeValue".toByteArray(charset)
```

Also try to pass multiple values in the request body in this way:

```
val requestBody =  "video_id = "+"ABCDE"+ "& audio_quality ="+ "256"
val charset = Charsets.UTF_8
val byteArray = requestBody.toByteArray(charset)
```